# Colour elements loaded with OBJLoader Three.js r74

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, mesh

Simple, I load my OBJ model exported with 3DS Max.

I want to colour **a single part** of the Object.

In the animate loop I do:

```
scene.traverse( function( object ) {
        scene.getObjectByName("ConcreteMeshName").material.color.set(0xff0000);                     
})
```

And **the whole model** is colored. Does anybody know why is this happening? Everything seems to be ok in the DOM tree.

Comment: do you add more that one object to the scene and one of them is named "ConcreteMeshName" or do you just call scene.add() once?

Comment: I call scene.add() once, for the object on the loader, like this:
`var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();    
loader.load( 'models/miau.obj',  
function ( object ){
contenido = object; 
scene.add(contenido);`
And i can see the all the THREE.Mesh on the DOM tree, but when I try to paint a single one, the complete model is colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material is shared all allong the geometry, so, when you try to colour a single object, you just can't, you have to assign a different material to each mesh in 3DS Max in order to differentiate them.